# How can I iterate over a list within a dict structure?

Tags: python, dictionary

I make an API call which returns a json response `stocks` like so (
[entire response](https://api.twelvedata.com/stocks?source=docs) I am trying to loop):

```
{
    "data": [{
        "symbol": "000",
        "name": "Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "exchange": "FSX",
        "country": "Germany",
        "type": "Common Stock"
    }, {
        "symbol": "000",
        "name": "Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "exchange": "Munich",
        "country": "Germany",
        "type": "Common Stock"
    }, {
```

Now I want to iterate over the items within `data` but I'm confused about the returned structure (looks like a dict in a list in a dict somewhat?)

What I've tried:

```
stocks = td.get_stocks_list().as_json()[0]

print(type(stocks)) # prints 'dict'

print(stocks) # however this only prints the second item, not the first nor the entire dict I want to loop:

{'symbol': '000', 'name': 'Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.', 'currency': 'EUR', 'exchange': 'Munich', 'country': 'Germany', 'type': 'Common Stock'}
```

So how to catch all items within `data` in the response?

Comment: Is it a copy error that `print(stocks_new)` is not indented?

Comment: Why do you have: `stocks_new = stock`? This just overwrites the previous `stocks_new = {}`. Did you mean: `stocks_new[stock.name] = stock`?

Comment: @quamrana I tried to assign the "Inner" part of the returned data to a new dict so I can iterate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah since the whole object is dict where in your snapshot has the key `data` which is list of nasty dicts you would need to do something like this:

```
dict = {
    “data”: [{
        “symbol”: “000”,
        “name”: “Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.“,
        “currency”: “EUR”,
        “exchange”: “FSX”,
        “country”: “Germany”,
        “type”: “Common Stock”
    }, {
        “symbol”: “000",
        “name”: “Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.“,
        “currency”: “EUR”,
        “exchange”: “Munich”,
        “country”: “Germany”,
        “type”: “Common Stock”
    }]
}
print(dict.keys())
print(list(dict.keys()))
for key in list(dict.keys()):
    print(key, ‘->‘, list(dict[key]) )
    for nasty_dict in list(dict[key]):
        print(nasty_dict, ‘->‘, list(dict[key]).index(nasty_dict))
        for k in nasty_dict:
            print(k, ‘->’, nasty_dict[k])
```

which would output you this:

```
dict_keys(['data'])
['data']
data -> [{'symbol': '000', 'name': 'Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.', 'currency': 'EUR', 'exchange': 'FSX', 'country': 'Germany', 'type': 'Common Stock'}, {'symbol': '000', 'name': 'Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.', 'currency': 'EUR', 'exchange': 'Munich', 'country': 'Germany', 'type': 'Common Stock'}]
{'symbol': '000', 'name': 'Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.', 'currency': 'EUR', 'exchange': 'FSX', 'country': 'Germany', 'type': 'Common Stock'} -> 0
symbol -> 000
name -> Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.
currency -> EUR
exchange -> FSX
country -> Germany
type -> Common Stock
{'symbol': '000', 'name': 'Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.', 'currency': 'EUR', 'exchange': 'Munich', 'country': 'Germany', 'type': 'Common Stock'} -> 1
symbol -> 000
name -> Greenvolt - Energias Renováveis, S.A.
currency -> EUR
exchange -> Munich
country -> Germany
type -> Common Stock
```

and that how you could iterate over all objects

Answer (score 1):

Your print command is outside of the loop so it should be

```
stocks_new = {}

for stock in stocks:
    stocks_new = stock
    print(stocks_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for the API call, using the `requests` module in python,  in your last case if you write the print inside the loop then it will work,

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://api.twelvedata.com/stocks?source=docs")
for _res in response.json()["data"]:
       print(_res)
       print(_res["country"])
```

I have also show an example on how can you access the keys like country inside the array of dict.

Comment: hm why does this not work `for stock in stocks["data"]` ? I'm using this sdk which returns it as json already: https://github.com/twelvedata/twelvedata-python#Time-series

Comment: can you check what does type(stocks) return it should return dict, then it will work, if it something else then there would be a different way to deal with it. I do not have the API key to your library so cannot test it myself.

Comment: @updated my answer, somehow it only returns a single item when I first access the list inside the response. Hmm

Answer (score -2):

As you had written your code before the edit of your question, the `print` statement was placed outside of the loop and only the last element of `stocks` would be printed.

This should print all elements of `stocks`:

```py
for stock in stocks:
    print(stock)
```